# Efficient way to convert HEX string into int in pyspark

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, hex

Is there an efficient way to convert a `StringType()` column with hexadecimal numbers (`0-9, A-F`) to 10 based int like `LongType()` in pyspark?

I can achieve this by `pandas_udf` like:

```
@F.pandas_udf('long')
def hex_to_long(sq):
    return pd.Series(np.int64(np.uint64([int(x, 16) for x in sq])))

df = df.withColumn('col_number', hex_to_long(F.col('col_with_hex_str')))
```

But this doesn't seem to be a very efficient. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way (perhaps without using any python based udf)?

EDIT: I know there are `conv` in the scala api of spark that can do this job as mentioned in [How to convert a column from hex string to long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930150/how-to-convert-a-column-from-hex-string-to-long) but I can't find the corresponding api in pyspark. It will be great if someone can give a hint about how to do that in pyspark.

Comment: @user10938362 Thanks for the link but that answer is in scala spark not pyspark.

Comment: @LouisYang converting from scala to pyspark is quite trivial. In this case I think you want: `df = df.withColumn('col_number', F.conv(F.col('col_with_hex_str'), 16, 10))`. Link to docs for [`pyspark.sql.functions.conv()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.conv)

Comment: @pault Thanks for pointing that out. I somehow miss that when I trying to find the corresponding API. Also, the linked question in Scala Spark doesn't have the best answer selected. And the title is unclear about what the context is (java or spark?). I would recommend to reopen this question and give a better answer in pyspark specifically.