# How to convert hex string to hex bytes format in PySpark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, hex

I am currently working on converting a SQL pipeline into PySpark, and got a little stuck on translating SQL's `from_hex` function to Pyspark. I saw some solutions that involve converting the string to an int, and then to hex bytes, but that seems rather inefficient. Is there an efficient way to convert the column that's a hex string to hex bytes?

For context, I need to join another table that is already in bytes format:

```
on i.joining_column = from_hex(a.joining_column)
```

where i is already in hex bytes format, and a is a string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449738/efficient-way-to-convert-hex-string-into-int-in-pyspark?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is about converting strings to ints, but wasn't sure if this was useful in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bultin function [`unhex`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#unhex) :

```
spark.sql("select hex('hex test') as hexa").show(truncate=False)
#+----------------+
#|hexa            |
#+----------------+
#|6865782074657374|
#+----------------+

spark.sql("select unhex('6865782074657374') as bytes").show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------+
#|bytes                    |
#+-------------------------+
#|[68 65 78 20 74 65 73 74]|
#+-------------------------+
```

The function is also available in DataFrame API : [`unhex`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unhex)